# Python custom function for sorting a list of objects

Tags: python, sorting

A list of `Point` class objects is given.
The `Point` class is as follows:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, value, segment, is_start=False):
        self.value = value
        self.is_start = is_start
```

The goal is to sort the list by the `value` attribute provided that if two objects have the same `value` attributes, the object whose `is_start` value is True should go before the object whose `is_start` value is False.

An example of input:

```
[Point(3, False), Point(3, True), Point(1, True),]
```

I've tried using `array.sort(key=lambda x: x.value)` and the output was:

```
[Point(1, True), Point(3, False), Point(3, True),]
```

But it doesn't satisfy the condition stated before (`Point(3, True)` should be before `Point(3, False)`).

An example of desired output:

```
[Point(1, True), Point(3, True), Point(3, False),]
```

What function to use to satisfy the stated condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```py
sorted(x, key=lambda x: (x.value, not x.is_start))
```